# What are current environments for combining LaTeX/MathJAX/... and handwritten notes/sketches/drawings?

Tags: graphics, editors, draw, sketch

I am pretty sure there must exist by now several editing environments where you could, using touchscreen, insert any kind of scribbling into TeX-generated output (or maybe even intersperse the source code with it). I just have no idea where to look for it. Does anyone know appropriate magic search keywords for googling?

On request from comments let me explain in more detail what I mean. I would like to have an environment, something like [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/), where I might, say, on a tablet, preliminarily free up some space either in the output or in the input, draw something in that space, and the system then would insert an image of my drawing into an appropriately formatted slot in the output.

Comment: I think this is not related to (La)TeX, but to the PDF viewer, etc.

Comment: @JouleV I believe it is, because the notes must fit properly into TeX output, so the system must process them accordingly somehow. If I just leave empty holes to fill them by hand later, there might be a problem with changing it during further editing.

Comment: I don't like extended discussions in comments. I will delete my previous comments, and so should you. My last comment: The more I read your comments, the less understandable your question is to me. Please explain _everything_ more in your question: how this is related to TeX, how you want the software to work, etc. I still keep my opinion that this question is blatantly off topic.

Comment: @JouleV OK will do that

Comment: You seem to be expecting some kind of magic.

Comment: @Johannes_B YES

Comment: Any luck so far?

Comment: @smapers Mmm frankly speaking it sort of lost its importance, now that everybody gives online talks with just handwritten notes in real time, inserting pictures when needed. And you can also scribble inside a pdf slide...